# invalid method parameters for eth_sendTransaction

Tags: json-rpc, ethereum

I am trying to make a transaction ( c++ client via json-rpc ) - just set "from" and "to" as the rest is marked optional. Also tried to add value but I still get:

```
ErrorMessage{code=-32602, message=INVALID_PARAMS: Invalid method parameters (invalid name and/or type) recognised}
```

both are addresses owned by me ( returned via eth_accounts ) - any hint on how to overcome this are welcome This is the request I try:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":{"from":"0x3edba223fdd11309a7f277882e0bfaa287f2676b","to":"0x42ec4438503f690dcc2939047e1e8cf6b9218f95","value":1},"id":1}
```

Comment: please post your transaction. otherwise difficult to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

params needs to be an array, try

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"0x3edba223fdd11309a7f277882e0bfaa287f2676b","to":"0x42ec4438503f690dcc2939047e1e8cf6b9218f95","value":1}],"id":1}
```

Comment: ah thanks - will try that soon - unfortunately it is not as simple as it sounds as it seems to be not possible with the json-rpc lib I use - also I am not sure why this is encapsulated in an array and how it then corresponds to the single string result

Comment: just tried it on the console and it gets me further - but strangely I did not get a hash back - just an empty-string